# Block access from pgAdmin to Postgres in kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, docker, kubernetes

We are trying to setup a pgAdmin but want to avoid that the root user could connect and create, update or delete anything.

We have create a new readonly-user for this case and this works fine. But it is still possible to create a server in pgAdmin with root data. Our idea was to block the connection for root but in kubernetes there are no static IPs for services. That means we cant block the root access without blocking the backend and keycloak.

Are there any other concepts we are missing but very helpful for our usecase?

Comment: Are you talking about the PostgreSQL bootstrap superuser (commonly called `postgres`)?

Comment: No the "root" user is the user which is created by docker image ENVs `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`. 
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres
This user has read and write access and I dont want to use this user for pgAdmin

Comment: Simply disallow remote connections in the `pg_hba.conf` file on the PostgreSQL server and reload PostgreSQL.

Comment: As said before the backend and the keycloak pod are connecting remote to the server.

Comment: Then configure `pg_hba.conf` so that it only allows access from the Kubernetes servers.

Comment: As said before the IPs are not static in kubernetes. So there is no difference possible between keycloak, backend and pgAdmin pod.

Comment: If you have no way to distinguish clients that you want to allow from clients that you want to block, you obviously cannot do it. Perhaps you should organize your servers so that you can distinguish them by IP range.

Comment: Also you may provide separate user for Keycloak and whatever. Alos you may do not tell "root" user's password to people who should not be able to use it.

Comment: Same problem with another user. There is no guarantee that somebody uses the credentials for the user with write-permissions. 
Also there is nobody "telling" the credentials to somebody which is not be able to use it, it is the fact that the credentials are in CI/CD pipeline variables in Gitlab, but this is not the question/topic. I am just surprised that Postgres has this big security issue when using it in kubernetes. I guessed it is possible to block or open the connection just for specific services in k8s.